# How to create transtions of page from left and right from middle page with two buttons?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two pages in JQM, login and register, default is login page and at the header I if click register transition happens to register and vice versa if you click on back in register you end at login.

```
    <div data-role="page" id="login-page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#register-page">Register</a>
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" class="ui-content-transparent" style="width: 40%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <form>

            </form>
            <input type="button" id="login" value="Login" class="large_input" style="min-height: 60px;">
        </div>

        <div data-position="fixed" data-role="footer">
            <h4 id="login_message"></h4>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="register-page" class="ui-content-transparent">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>CVE Registration</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" class="ui-content-transparent" style="width: 40%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <form>


            </form>
            <input type="button" id="register" value="Register" class="large_input" style="min-height: 60px;">
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h4 id="register_message"></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to set default (add new page with two big buttons Login and Register) new page and when user click on Login button to make transition from left to Login page and when clicks on Register to make transition from right on Register page.

```
Login Page ====> Default with two buttons <==== Register Page
```

How to do this in JQM ? ( I know to slide divs in jquery but with JQM and pages it seems different to me).

Answer (score 0):

you need some js do do that, if you want to make it scroll smooth

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 0):

Try as shown below to go left to login page,

```
<a href="#Loginpage" data-direction="reverse">Login</a>
```

data-direction="reverse" is used to go back

Answer (score 0):

These two buttons(inside header) will do, check DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Rdfxs/3/

```
<div data-role="page" id="login-page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#register-page" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-transition="slide">Register</a>
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="ui-content-transparent" style="width: 40%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <form>
        </form>
        <input type="button" id="login" value="Login" class="large_input" style="min-height: 60px;">
    </div>
    <div data-position="fixed" data-role="footer">
        <h4 id="login_message"></h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="register-page" class="ui-content-transparent">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#login-page" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Login</a>
        <h1>CVE Registration</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="ui-content-transparent" style="width: 40%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <form>
        </form>
        <input type="button" id="register" value="Register" class="large_input" style="min-height: 60px;">
    </div>
</div>
```